# Is there any way for jscs to ignore rules per file, block or line?

Tags: jscs

I'm looking for a way for jscs (JavaScript Code Style) do the same behavior as jshint to ignore certain rules per file with a comment at the top, or per line, with a start and end comment.

jshint example to ignore a specific rule in the file :

```
/* jshint undef: false */
```

jshint example to ignore a specific rule in a block:

```
// Code here will be linted with JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:start */
// Code here will be linted with ignored by JSHint.
/* jshint ignore:end */
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

This is available since jscs 1.6.0

#### For a file scope:

Put this on top of the file to ignore all rules

```
// jscs:disable
```

Put this on top of the file to ignore a specific rule:

```
// jscs:disable specificRule
```

Also for ignoring the whole file you can add it to **.jscsrc**, adding an entry to **excludeFiles**.

#### For block scope:

To ignore all rules

```
// Code here will be linted with JSCS.
// jscs:disable
// Code here will be ignored by JSCS.
// jscs:enable
```

To ignore a specific rule:

```
// Code here will be linted with JSCS.
// jscs:disable specificRule
// Code here will be ignored by JSCS.
// jscs:enable specificRule
```

Comment: I assume ignoring all rules in a codeblock would be
```//jscs:disable
// Code here will be ignored by JSCS.
//jscs:enable```

Comment: Just a quick note on file scope. You can also ignore files/directories by creating `.jscsrc` file and adding `excludeFiles` key with the name of the file/directories as value. There has been some talks on having `.jscsignore` file but it will be coming in 2.0, I believe.

Comment: add space after `//` to not trigger the `requireSpaceAfterLineComment` rule like @AndrewAnthonyGerst suggests

Answer (score 15):

to disable a particular rule for just the one line

```
// jscs:ignore maximumLineLength
```

Answer (score 3):

To ignore the whole file just add the following line at the top of the file.

```
// jscs:disable
```